# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

The error is

> linux/FIT/fit: symbol lookup error: linux/FIT/fit: undefined symbol:
>   FT_Get_Font_Format

This is part of an Android build.

It doesn't tell me which `.so` it searched.

I searched for that symbol

```
sudo grep -F "FT_Get_Font_Format" / -r --include="*.so*"
```

And it's in a bunch of `.so` files.

**QUESTION**

How do I find out which `.so` file it's looking for?

Comment: It's not looking for a `.so`, it's looking for a symbol from a `.so`. What libraries are you linking, and why do they apparently not have the symbol is more the question.

Comment: @l'L'l this error is from a utility that is running

Comment: Maybe try `ldd <utility name>` to see which libraries it's linked to.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't tell me which .so it searched.

It searched *all* of the loaded libraries.

Unlike on Windows, the UNIX linker doesn't record which symbol is provided by which library, and the loader searches all currently loaded libraries (in order of their loading) for all of the symbols it needs to resolve.

> I searched for that symbol
>   `sudo grep -F "FT_Get_Font_Format" / -r --include="*.so*"`

That command does not distinguish between definition and references to the symbol, therefore this conclusion:

> And it's in a bunch of .so files.

doesn't tell you anything useful.

The correct way to search for *definition* of the symbol would be:

```
find / -name '*.so*' -type f -print0 |
  xargs -o nm -AD | egrep ' [TDW] FT_Get_Font_Format'
```

Or you can just google it, and discover that it's part of FreeType API, and should be in `libfreetype.so`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908174/50617) suggests that your version of freetype may be too old.